# Load Honda CB400 inside 2003 Kia Sedona?

Tags: motorcycle, sedona

I have the car, but I don't have the motorcycle. I plan to bring the motorcycle back home.

The maximum height the car can load is 40 inch.

About the motorcycle, from Wikipedia, the seat height is 29.7 inch.

I just wonder if this CB400 motorcycle can be loaded into my 2003 Kia Sedona, or any workaround to make it fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't fit inside, so I see as you have four options:

The first option is not a good option, nor is it overall a *safe* option (read: try at your own risk). What you can do is to leave your back hatch open and put just the front tire of the bike there, with the rear tire still on the ground, transmission in neutral. Then get PLENTY of rope and tie the front end (forks and handle bars) of the bike in so it is solid and doe as not move. In this manner the bike trails on home behind you and you are on your merry way.

The second, and better option, is to pay someone some (or ask someone) to ride it to your home for you, and you give them a ride back to where they need to go.

The third option, like unto the second option, is to have someone give you a ride to the bike, and you ride it home.

The fourth option is to find someone with a trailer (utility or bike), and have them tow it home for you.

Obviously, options 2-4 are the better options here. Number one might work, *maybe*, but I'd leave that option for the last, final, ***desperate*** option in your arsenal.

Comment: Have you ever used option 1?

Comment: @ChrisMcCall ... no but I've seen it done. You just have to ensure it's rock solid.